# How to automatically resize an AWT component after changing it's contents?

Tags: java, awt

I have an AWT `Label` inside a `Panel` with `FlowLayout`. I want to dynamically change the Labels text and resize it to the required width.

I have only found answers to the Swing version of this problem (`setPrototypeDisplayValue()`), but I have to stick with AWT since this is a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call invalidate(), which will then tell the parent container (your Panel) to redraw itself.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#invalidate()

Comment: That didn't do anything, but looking trough that docpage I've found doLayout() which does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!